# Find the sum of real values of X

Tags: algebra-precalculus

1. What is the domain of 
   $$f(x) = (x^2 - 5x + 5) ^ {x^2+4x-60} $$
2. Find the sum of real values of x satisfying the equation
   $$(x^2-5x+5)^ {x^2+4x-60} = 1$$

domain of the function is important as the Q.2 answer may be 3 if Domain is all values of x or may be 1 if base is taken only positive

Comment: What have to tried ? For the 1st question, is there any obvious values of $x$ for which $f(x)$ would not be defined ?

Comment: I have doubt about the base function i.e  $$ x^2-5x+5 $$, should it be positive for the given function  f(x) to be defined

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, exponentiating a negative number still gives you some other number.

Comment: The only problematic exponent I know of is $0^0$. So that would be a case worth checking.

Comment: Is there anything like $$ f(x)^ {g(x)} $$ is defined for only those values of x for which  $$ f(x) > 0 $$

Comment: Where are you getting that definition from ? I might be wrong, but I have never encountered a statement like that.

Comment: I think this is a convention which is followed for variable function raised to power variable function, because else it will lead to discontinuity at infinitely many points between even a very small interval of x values. Even I am not sure !!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37904/discussion-between-rt6-and-aashish).

Comment: The equation $a^b=1$ puts some serious restrictions on the (real) values of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Is f a real or complex function.  I don't know how to do negative bases to rational exponents with even denominators or to irrational powers.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can't evaluate $0^b \forall b<=0$, as well as $a^b$ where $a <= 0$ and $b \notin \mathbb{Z}$. For example,  $(-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is undefined over $R$. So the domain of $f(x)$ is where, either $x^2-5x+5>0$ or $x^2+4x-60\in \mathbb{Z}$. Solve for it, $x^2-5x+5>0 \iff x<{5\over2}-\sqrt{5\over4} or x>{5\over2}+\sqrt{5\over4}$. You can solve yourself the second condition.
2. If $a^b=1$ and $b \in \mathbb{Z} $, then $a = 1$.
   $$x^2-5x+5 = 1 $$
   $$\iff x^2-5x+4=0$$
   $$\iff (x-1)(x-4)=0$$
   $$\iff x \in \{1, 4\} $$

Comment: What is the definition of $N^*$ ? do you mean $\mathbb{N} $ ?

Comment: $N^*$ is the set $\mathbb{N}$ without 0. I have edited it, however.